# Python range with Uneven gap

Tags: python, python-3.x

Today I had a python exam where following question was asked:

Given the following code extract, Complete the code so the output is: `10 7 5`.

```
nums = list (range (?,?,?))

print(nums)
```

How is it possible to get such output in python using range function?

Comment: Have you approached your professor to see if it's supposed to be 10, 7, 4? Seems like the most likely scenario tbh.

Comment: What does "complete the code" mean?  Complete it so that it works with only what's given or complete it so that you produce the desired result?

Comment: Loocid, No, I haven't asked. I wanted to discuss about it.

Comment: Mark, You have to fill in the 3 '?' with any syntax or number to get desired output.

Comment: Gotcha. I was just seeing what constraints there are. Weird question!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible.  Maybe the question was only there to see how much time you'd waste trying to come up with an answer?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

not sure if this answer the question, provided we can fill in any syntax to the ? as long it produce the result.

- 1st ? = `10`
- 2nd ? = `4`
- 3rd ? = `-3))+(([5]`
- 

```
# nums = list(range(   ?  ,  ?  ,      ?       ))
nums   = list(range(  10  ,  4  ,  -3))+(([5]  ))
print(nums)
# nums = [10,7,5]
```

Comment: i think this is just one of the variant, following this method, we should have few answer

Comment: Anyway the code works and that's what they want.

Comment: `nums = list(range (0,1,1)) and (([10, 7, 5]))` also works.

Comment: It's clever people like you that make SQL injection such a menace.  https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 11):

There is no sane way to get the result required. The meat of the problem is that the built in `range` is strict about its inputs and its definition. It only accepts integers. The only way to get the required answer is to override one of the built ins. But you could override any of them.

```
range = lambda x, y, z: [10, 7, 5]
list = lambda x: [10, 7, 5]
print = lambda x: sys.stdout.write([10, 7, 5])
```

On a scale of C# minor what's your favorite color? Mine's triangle.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how that works! But you can get that output with the advanced range function in NumPy, since it allows the use of floats:

```
import numpy as np

nums = np.arange(10, 3, -2.6)
print(np.rint(nums))
```

Out: [10.  7.  5.]

in the list we get 10, 7.4 and 4.8, and the `rint` function rounds them up to 10, 7 and 5. Maybe there is a way to use `range` with floats as well?

Comment: You can't use vanilla range with floats. (First thing I tried.) :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't what the OP wants but maybe you could try using list comprehensions. You could use this trick. For example,

```py
num = list(x for x in range(11,3,-1) if x==10 or x==7 or x==5)
print(num)
```

This outputs `[10,7,5]`.

Comment: You can not add anything between `list(` and `range(` because there's no `?`

Comment: YQstack, there must me print(num)

Comment: AnishSapkota sorry, my fault for typo. @igorkf I know. That's why I said this is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
nums = list(range(10, 2, -3)[:2]) + ([5] )    
print(nums)
[10, 7, 5]
```

- 10
- 2
- -3)[:2]) + ([5]